Body in solar system causing a tidally locked planet to briefly tilt
I have a tidally locked planet with a slight wobble, and an in-universe explanation (or at least hand-waving) as to why it briefly tilts every hundred years, creating a brief (several hour) change in the temperature.
I was thinking it would be interesting if a passing body, say a pluto-type planet on an offset orbit, caused this effect, but I can't visualize how it would work.
So my question is: Could a body in the same system cause a tidally locked planet to tilt toward (or away) from its star, and if it did, would there be any force to pull it back? Like, wouldn't the planet just stay tilted (or start rotating, for that matter) if it got affected by this other body?

It would be helpful if you explained what "tilt" is supposed to mean.

Tilt, as in axial tilt. I'm sorry, I don't know how to describe it any better than that.

Newton law states that a body will keep its motion until a force acts on it.
If an external force acts on the planet and causes it to tilt away or toward its star, the motion will continue until another force acts to stop it.
However there is a bigger problem: changing the rotation axis of a body by means of sole gravitational interaction is hardly possible, because it requires exerting a momentum which gravitational forces do not do on a spherically symmetrical body.
Either your planet is far from being a sphere (but then it would not be a planet) or you have to recur to something else, like a massive impact event which shifts the rotational axis. But the impact event, for what I said above, would not "bounce back".
A passing body would at most just pull the orbit due to its effect on the orbital velocity.

It wouldn't have to be a sphere. But, yeah, I think you're right.

Assuming that by "tilt" the question means exposing a different part of the planet to the light from the star, then there is no need for a third body; an elliptic orbit is enough.
Practical example: the Moon is tidally locked to the Earth. If the orbit of the Moon was perfectly circular and its axis of rotation was exactly perpendicular to its orbital plane, we could only ever see one half of the surface of the Moon. But in reality we get to see about 59% of it. How come?
The orbit of the Moon around the Earth is an ellipse. This means that seen from Earth the Moon appears to move faster when it is nearest to the Earth, and slower when it is farthest from the Earth. But the rotation of the Moon around its own axis is almost perfectly uniform. As a consequence, the rotation of the Moon around its axis appears to get ahead of its position or fall behind its position depending on where the Moon is on its orbit.
For details, see the Wikipedia article on libration, specifically optical libration in longitude.
Here is a nice picture showing the aspect of the full Moon at opposite libration points:

Full Moon at opposite librations, scaled for equal diameter. Image by Jürgen Kahlhöfer, available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International license.

Yes! This is my current explanation, though I don't go into much detail. Thank you for the reassurance I was on the right track.
